# delete code in string with loop when read PDF with php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I´m traying to read PDF file with this `library`, `\Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();` in `laravel 5.6`

i´m reading all my pdf ok, i´m getting all my content ok. i´m deleting headers from my PDF and i´m inserting by line in array.

and this it´s data:

```
    [0] =>  MARTIN CARRILLO MARIA ESMERALDA ALHAMBRA 10 958 54 38 93
    [1] => 1745591 ESPIGARES DIAS JOSE ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 11 958 54 33 32
    [2] => 1770062 GUTIERREZ TITOS JOSE MANUEL ALHAMBRA 12 958 54 04 10
    [3] => 1793228 MARTIN COBOS ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 18 958 54 33 28
    [4] => 1768807 GOMEZ CARRILLO JOSE ALHAMBRA 20 958 54 32 72
    [5] => 1830072 RODRIGUEZ RUANO BUENAVENTURA ALHAMBRA 21 958 54 35 86
    [6] => 1759534 GARCIA ARIAS MARIA ISABEL ALHAMBRA 22 958 54 07 87
    [7] => 1831938 RODRIGUEZ JIMENEZ MIGUEL ALHAMBRA 27 958 54 08 77
    [8] => 1722022 GUTIERREZ FERNANDEZ AMANDA HILDA ALHAMBRA 3 958 49 98 62
    [9] => 1746872 DIAZ FLORIAN DOLORES ALHAMBRA 30 958 54 33 99
    [10] => 1817587 PEREZ LASTRA SAUL ADAN ALHAMBRA 32 958 54 31 46
    [11] => 1724006 AMIGO MOLINA MARIA MATILDE ALHAMBRA 35 958 54 31 91
    [12] => 1745604 ESPIGARES GOMEZ JORGE ALHAMBRA 37 958 54 02 22
    [13] => 1745595 ESPIGARES ESPIGARES JOSE ALHAMBRA 40 958 54 31 83
```

i need delete firt numbers, it´s code from this client. i´m doing this for delete code, but always it´s doing in firts element.

This is my code to tray delete my code from all string...

```
// loop to get data line
for($i=0; $i<count($dataByLine); $i++){
   // delete code
   $numberCode = stripos($dataByLine[$i], " ");
   $codeClear = substr($text, 0, $numberCode);
   $dataByLine = str_replace($codeClear, "", $dataByLine);

   print_r($dataByLine);
}
```

this `print_r()` it´s my first content array. As you can see in my array, first element it´s without code.. but the rest, have code.

how i can to delete all code from this string¿?

thanks for help and read. Sorry for my english

**updated**

```
// loop to get data line
foreach($dataByLine as &$line){                        
   //$line = preg_replace('/^[\d]+/','',$line);
   $line = ltrim($line,"0123456789");

   array_push($dataList, $line);
}

print_r($dataList);
```

this it´s result:

```
    [0] =>  1794707 MARTIN CARRILLO MARIA ESMERALDA ALHAMBRA 10 958 54 38 93
    [1] =>  ESPIGARES DIAS JOSE ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 11 958 54 33 32
    [2] =>  GUTIERREZ TITOS JOSE MANUEL ALHAMBRA 12 958 54 04 10
    [3] =>  MARTIN COBOS ANTONIO ALHAMBRA 18 958 54 33 28
    [4] =>  GOMEZ CARRILLO JOSE ALHAMBRA 20 958 54 32 72
    [5] =>  RODRIGUEZ RUANO BUENAVENTURA ALHAMBRA 21 958 54 35 86
    [6] =>  GARCIA ARIAS MARIA ISABEL ALHAMBRA 22 958 54 07 87
    [7] =>  RODRIGUEZ JIMENEZ MIGUEL ALHAMBRA 27 958 54 08 77
    [8] =>  GUTIERREZ FERNANDEZ AMANDA HILDA ALHAMBRA 3 958 49 98 62
    [9] =>  DIAZ FLORIAN DOLORES ALHAMBRA 30 958 54 33 99
```

Comment: `ltrim($string, "0123456789");`? Regex replace `^[\d]+` for `''`?

Comment: @pavel thanks for your  i don´t understand very well your response because i need all digit from my string except code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `foreach()` so that you can use calling by reference option (useful in your case)

Use `ltirm()`

```
foreach($dataByLine as &$line){

    $line = ltrim($line,"0123456789");
    
    //Or you can do $line = preg_replace('/^[\d]+/','',$line);
}
print_r($dataByLine);
```